# Rebuild only FutureBuilder widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting a random value from some API, and I have a condition for it. If the condition is true, I will return a widget, else I want to change the random value and get another random value from the API again.
I need to rebuild just the `FutureBuilder` widget, and I dont know how to do this, I got an error while using `setState` which is `setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.`
This is my code so far:

```
FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
                    future: API.get_pets(randomly_select_URL()),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        List<dynamic>? pet_data = snapshot.data;

                        if (dropDownIsSelected == true) {
                          var number_of_parameters = snapshot.data!.length;
                          var random_pet = random.nextInt(number_of_parameters);
                          var category =
                              pet_data![random_pet].category.toString();
                          var photoURL =
                              pet_data![random_pet].photoUrls.toString();
                          if (notEqualsIgnoreCase(category, "Kitty") ||
                              notEqualsIgnoreCase(category, "Puppy") ||
                              notEqualsIgnoreCase(category, "Fish") ||
                              notEqualsIgnoreCase(category, "Hedgehog") ||
                              notEqualsIgnoreCase(category, "Bunny") ||
                              photoURL.length == 0) {
                                print("NOT IN CATEGORY");
                                random_pet = random.nextInt(number_of_parameters);
                              }
                          else {
                            return Random_Card();
                          }
                          
                        }
```

Comment: `future: API.get_pets(randomly_select_URL())` Don't build the future as the future: parameter in FutureBuilder. See the first few paragraphs of the FutureBuilder documentation, or see my video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqE-J8YJnpg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you need, but I see two potential errors.

1. `FutureBuilder` should be used with a `StatefulWidget` in which your `Future` is a property initialized in `initState`;
2. The error you're receiving is telling you: "you asked me to perform a rebuild even though I didn't even finish to render this frame, and that's awkard". By design, the Flutter framework throws in these scenarios.

It's easier done than said, so, here's what I'd try (I didn't test this):

```dart
// Warning: pseudocode ahead!

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  Future<int>? myFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myFuture = // your API call
  }

  void requestAgain() {
    setState(() {
      myFuture = // another API call
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: myFuture,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        var output = "";
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) output = "loading...";
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          output = "Now we have: ${snapshot.data}";
          if (someCondition) {
            // !
            WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
              requestAgain();
            });
          }
        }
        if (snapshot.hasError) output = "Woops, something went wrong";

      },
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see when `someCondition` is true we're appending your API call *after* Flutter finished rendering the current frame; this is a hacky workaround though, that might or might not be the ideal solution.

I highly recommend to use [`Riverpod`](https://riverpod.dev/) to handle this problem (see [FutureProvider](https://riverpod.dev/docs/providers/future_provider/)).

Comment: I am using a `StatefulWidget`, I used your code but it stuck in a loop of `requestAgain`

Comment: Indeed this isn't optimal as the "request and try again" is not explicitly written. The loop may happen if you condition is never met because of API calls (or maybe my implementation error). I highly suggest learning Riverpod its `FutureProvider` class to implement what you need in your app.

Answer (score 0):

In a Statefull or Stateless widget, mix a StatefullBuilder and a FutureBuilder to reset only the StatefullBuilder content.

Here is a working example with a StatelessWidget:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  Future myFuture() async {
    print("reloading");
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    return true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, subState) {
      return Column(children: [
        FutureBuilder(
            future: myFuture(),
            builder: (context, snapShot) {
              return Text('hasData:${snapShot.hasData} | at: ${DateTime.now()}');
            }),
        InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              subState(() {});
            },
            child: Text("Call Future"))
      ]);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use Future.delayed(Duration.zero) in the top of your future function and all things will works fine

```
Future<void> testFunction(){
Future.delayed(Duration.zero);
//then type your future code here
}
```

or if you are using alert dialog or anything  else you have to use delayed duration in the top of your code

Comment: also if you can add your future function code that will be more useful and may give you more help